# nginx configuration server_name is wrong but website is still working?

Tags: nginx

I only want to allow access to my server from one domain. Lets say my domain is called "mydomain.mydomain.com" (yes, it is a subdomain).

Normally I would write everywhere server_name mydomain.mydomain.com, but I changed it to a non-existing domain and I can still enter the website? Why is my website working also from other domains? I know nginx is normally using the first server-block if no server_name is found, but my first server-block is my catch-all non-existing domain block. I defined `server_name _;` and `default_server`, but still, my website is working.

I have the following configuration:

```
server {
    #If server_name mydomain.mydomain.com is not found return 444
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 444;
}

# redirect all traffic to https if the domain is mydomain.mydomain.com (server_name)
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    #-------------------------------------------
    # I CHANGE HERE TO A NON-EXISTING DOMAIN AND MY WEBSITE IS STILL WORKING?!?!?
    #-------------------------------------------
    server_name nonExistingDomain.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}


server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    root /config/www;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    #-------------------------------------------
    # I CHANGE HERE TO A NON-EXISTING DOMAIN AND MY WEBSITE IS STILL WORKING?!?!?
    #-------------------------------------------
    server_name nonExistingDomain.com;

    # enable subfolder method reverse proxy confs
    include /config/nginx/proxy-confs/*.subfolder.conf;

    # all ssl related config moved to ssl.conf
    include /config/nginx/ssl.conf;

    client_max_body_size 0;

    error_page 404 =200 /portal;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" always;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";

    location = / {
        return 301 https://mydomain.mydomain.com/portal;
        #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html /index.php?$args =404;
    }

    location /pea {
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host:$server_port;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/pea;

       # do not pass the CORS header from the response of the proxied server to the
       # client
       #proxy_hide_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin';
    }

    location /portal {
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host:$server_port;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_pass http://localhost:8180/portal;
    }

    location /auth {
        proxy_set_header    Host               $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host   $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Port   $server_port;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
        proxy_pass          http://localhost:8280/auth;
    }
}
```

Comment: if you put a file called `mydomain.mydomain.com` in your `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` folder, it will still be served. Same applies if you pointed your ip address to said domain and all this config is in `default` file.

Comment: @Sry, I still dont understand. In my sites-enabled folder I have only one file "default" with de above configuration. Do I have to create another file with mydomain.mydomain.com?

Comment: yes or rename the default file to mydomain.mydomain.com, that way when you go to nonexistingdomain.mydomain.com, it will not serve the website

Comment: I renamed default to my real name with the real, not faked server_name. After that I could not open the website anymore. Isnt it useless to have the command 'server_name' if I would only have to rename the file to the domain I would like to serve? I thought I can handle all domains in the default file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are listening to the IpV6 network socket in your server blocks where you change domain to non-existent. Since there are no other such server blocks, they are the *default* for those IPv6 ports.

Note that your first server block is default only for IPv4 network socket `listen 80 default_server;`.

Thus the behavior can be explained only by the fact that you are connecting/testing over IpV6.

To avoid inconsistency, use `default_server` for all your listen options. E.g. in the first server block add default server for IPv6 too:

```
server {
    #If server_name mydomain.mydomain.com is not found return 444
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 444;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! ipv6, never thought on this